# Accessing APIM custom domain directly via Browser

Tags: azure, soap, azure-devops, azure-api-management

I have created custom domain in Azure APIM , and the API created is using SOAP protocol. I need to have the custom domain to be opened directly from browser so as to import the WSDL document directly from the SOAP UI , all the API operations are successfully getting called with 200OK from SOAP UI, however I need to make the custom domain as directly accessible from internet browser so as to import the WSDL document.
I even checked the default build in Gateway URL which also does not get directly opened in browser,  the error for directly accessing the custom domain or build in gateway URL is 404 (resource not found ), the url which I am trying to hit is the custom domain/services/name.wsdl .

Can any one please suggest how to make the custom domain or build in gateway URL as directly opened (accessible) from browser .

Answer (score 0):

With the integration between Azure API Management and [Azure Arc on Kubernetes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-arc/kubernetes/overview), you can deploy the API Management gateway component as an extension in an Azure Arc-enabled Kubernetes cluster.

**Deploy the API Management gateway extension using Azure portal**

1. In the Azure portal, navigate to your Azure Arc-connected cluster.
2. In the left menu, select Extensions (preview) > + Add > API Management gateway (preview).
3. Select Create.
4. In the Install API Management gateway window, configure the gateway extension:

- Select the subscription and resource group for your API Management instance.
- In Gateway details, select the API Management instance and Gateway name. Enter a Namespace scope for your extension and optionally a number of Replicas, if supported in your API Management service tier.
- In Kubernetes configuration, select the default configuration or a different configuration for your cluster.

[image]

5. On the Monitoring tab, optionally enable monitoring to upload metrics tracking requests to the gateway and backend. If enabled, select an existing Log Analytics workspace.
6. Select Review + install and then Install.